# Worklight 6.1 and Cordova 3 plugins

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any documentation for using Cordova 3.0 plugins with Worklight 6.1?

I have read the post:
[Is there a tool to install an existing Cordova 3 plugin into a Worklight 6.1 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003350/is-there-a-tool-to-install-an-existing-cordova-3-plugin-into-a-worklight-6-1-app)

It was several months ago so may be somekind of documentation was generated.

I have also created a RFE about this:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=53781

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no built-in support for pre-existing Cordova 3 plug-ins.

The way around it until proper plugman-like support is added, is to create a new Cordova plug-in [by following the instructions in the Worklight Getting Started training materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) and copying over the logic of the plug-in into yours.

Related question:

- [Add custom cordova plugin to IBM Worklight 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704574/add-custom-cordova-plugin-to-ibm-worklight-6-1)